# AutoHotkey: Press a button every x seconds while mouse-button y is pressed down

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible.

While I hold mouse-button 4 ( back ) down, it should execute pressing down the combination ctrl+g every 50 ms.

I can do it with my Logitech mouse, but I need to do it with a no name mouse. I dunno if AutoHotkey allows it.

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: To determine the designation for an unknown button/key. Double click on the AHK icon. Press ctrl-K in the window to open the key history. Press the button in question. Press F5. You'll get something like this
 `04  000   d 5.37 MButton        
    04  000   u 0.17 MButton        
    74  03F   d 0.86 F5` This shows the Middle Mouse Button going down, up, then F5 down.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
XButton1::
    while (GetKeyState("XButton1", "P")) {
        SendInput, ^g
        Sleep, 50
    }
return
```

Comment: So it works! That's friggin awesome. Is it possible to make the script only execute in a specific application? Like, say if I have Notepad++ up, then the mouse button script should ONLY work in Notepad++ nowhere else. Or a game or anything.

Comment: Oh, I also noticed this ONLY works with pressing the XButton1, but if I for example have shift+XButton1 pressed, it doesn't work.

Comment: @DonSalva Check out the [`#If`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_If.htm) directive and the [hotkey docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm), it should have some info about how to use modifiers.